# Docker-compose postgreSQL permission error

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

I have a problem with docker-compose postgreSQL, I am working on Windows WSL 2 + Docker Desktop. When I run docker-compose on linux server it works good, but when I try to start it locally I'm getting next error:

```
postgres      | chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
ngnix         | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
postgres      | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres      | This user must also own the server process.
postgres      |
postgres      | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres      | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres      | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres      |
postgres      | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres      |
ngnix         | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
ngnix         | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
postgres      | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Operation not permitted
ngnix         | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
postgres exited with code 1
```

I tried to change permission on all project like this => `chmod 777 -R project_folder`

Dcoker-compose.yml:

```
postgresdb:
    container_name: postgres
    build:
      context: ./docker/postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password123
    volumes:
    - ./docker/postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

No ideas, how to resolve it. Help me please!

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using Docker Volumes for the data directory, instead of the relative path?

Comment: Don't have reasons, I am newbie in dockers systems :)

Comment: You are running in WSL (Which is Linux). Try to open the ./postgres_data directory with the command: chmod 777 ./postgres_data. And restart the compose file.

Answer (score 5):

So my guess here is, that since you are mounting a directory relative to the docker-compose file as "data" directory in WSL, the permission error occurs. You can try to fix these permissions (chmod, chown etc the local directory).

You could also use ["named" volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) - which *should* get rid of the permission problem as well.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

services:
  # ...
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to start `build` from Windows PowerShell, then there is no issue with permissions.

Comment: beside your solution that worked, my solution was to change back to mac...

Answer (score 1):

Update the mount options for the directory in the WSL 2 instance's /etc/wsl.conf file by adding the following lines:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=22,fmask=11"
```

then

wsl --shutdown

It's work for me

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed (at least in my case) by editing /etc/wsl.conf, as Hanson said in the other answer.  However, the only option you should need to set is to enable metadata:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

Close all instances/terminals for the WSL VM, wait at least 8 seconds for the processes to stop, and then restart.

The defaults for uid, gid, umask, and fmask should work fine.  For more on the defaults and settings in /etc/wsl.conf: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configuration-settings-for-wslconf

For more on file permissions interation between Windows and Linux through WSL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions